# Why does this code give me a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I am trying to generate 2 matrices to multiply them later, but my code doesn't work!
It gives me "segmentation fault 'core dumped'"

Here is my code:

```
double *c;
void populate(int size,double *a,double *b)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            *(a+i*size+j)=1+rand()%100;
            *(b+i*size+j)=1+rand()%100;
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"You must Enter (..M..)for the size of M*M Matrix ,, try again\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (atoi(argv[1]) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d must be > 0\n", atoi(argv[1]));
        return -1;
    }

    const int M=atoi(argv[1]); // size M*M

    double *a;
    double *b;
    populate(M,a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you haven't allocated memory for a, b and c yet. populate function is anyway going to go bust

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you never allocate space for `a` or `b`.

As they are, `a` and `b` don't point to valid memory, when you try to write to wherever they point you are apparently accessing memory that is illegal to your program, hence causing a Segmentation Fault.

Try this

```
double *a;
double *b;

a = malloc(M * M * sizeof(double));
if (a == NULL)
    return -1;
b = malloc(M * M * sizeof(double));
if (b == NULL)
{
    free(a);
    return -1;
}
populate(M, a, b);
```

and mixing declarations with code in c, makes the code look ugly.

Comment: I'm afraid you are allocating vectors, not square matrices.

Comment: @chqrlie I am afraid you are right. And regarding your answer, I do not like `calloc()` if you are going to explicitly initialize the matrix, because it might hide some subtle bugs. But still, since you did address the issue it deserves an upvote.

Comment: Yes , I forgot to allocate space for my matrices ,,, thank you so much :D @iharob

Answer (score 4):

You need to allocate these matrices:

```
double *a = calloc(M * M, sizeof(double));
double *b = calloc(M * M, sizeof(double));
if (a == NULL || b == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory for %d x %d matrices\n", M, M);
    exit(1);
}
populate(M,a,b);
```